# What is http response status of 508?

Tags: apache, http

On my website, when loading images/videos, sometimes I get errors in the console like:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 508 (Loop Detected)
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: did you check your server-side code for possible infinite loops in your program logic?

Answer (score 5):

You can look up the definition of any officially registered HTTP status code using the IANA status code registry at http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml, which would lead you to http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc5842.html#status.508.loop.detected.

In this case, it's also possible that somebody is misusing the status code for something else; does it come with a response body?

Answer (score 1):

Try delays between each call, load a single link at a time from a single IP or use proxy.