# Volley Unexpected Response Code 508. Where is it?

Tags: php, android, sql, android-volley, http-response-codes

**Please note that I know a response code 508 means that there was an infinite loop somewhere.** My problem is I do not know where. Everything looks like it should be working, but I get the error. Thanks for any help and suggestions you may have.

**My PHP File:**

```
<?php

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $location = $_POST["location"];
    $locationName = $_POST["locationName"];

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;

    $con = mysqli_connect("website.xom", "username", "password", "dbname");

    switch($location) {
        case "1":
            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE user SET locationName1=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $locationName, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);
            $response["success"] = true;
            break;
        case "2":
            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE user SET locationName2=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $locationName, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);
            $response["success"] = true;
            break;
        case "3":
            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE user SET locationName3=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $locationName, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);
            $response["success"] = true;
            break;
        case "4":
            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE user SET locationName4=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $locationName, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);
            $response["success"] = true;
            break;
        case "5":
            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE user SET locationName5=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $locationName, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);
            $response["success"] = true;
            break;
        case "6":
            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE user SET locationName6=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $locationName, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);
            $response["success"] = true;
            break;
        case "7":
            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE user SET locationName7=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $locationName, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);
            $response["success"] = true;
            break;
        default:
            $response["success"] = false;
            break;
    }

    $con = null;
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is http response status of 508?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30529792/what-is-http-response-status-of-508)

Comment: I already said I know what HTTP Response 508 is. I don't know what's causing the error in this code though. There are no loops to cause the error

Comment: maybe its the query being run?

Comment: Can you show us the full network response and the headers?

Comment: That is the full code. There is nothing else in that file. It is used as a StringRequest coming from an android app