# Website gets a 508 error but I can't find it anywhere

Tags: jquery, datatables, setinterval

I have a simple site for registering volunteers for a specific venue. The system shows a table with invited participants and a table with registered participants. I use DataTables for both tables. To refresh the tables I use the table.ajax.reload() function with setInterval() every 5 seconds.

Usually the system works flawless, but this Saturday it went totally haywire throwing a lot of "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 508 ()" and also a "GET https://XXXX 508 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2".

I can't find any loop in the code anywhere. The only difference is that instead of being 20 simultaneous users, this time there were 42 users. I'm totally lost on finding a solution, so I hope that you guys can help pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: try it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30529792/what-is-http-response-status-of-508 may this helpful !